# how to read RUNTIME_CLASS info from dll

Tags: dll, mfc

We have 1 legacy MFC project (exe) use sth like IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(ItemA, BaseItem, 0) for serialization, recently we found ItemA also involve view operation, so we decided to separate the persistence part to individual module (dll). However exception is raised when we try to deserialize from external file after applying the changes.

I found IMPLEMENT_SERIAL macro did sth like registration locally as below:

```
#define IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(class_name, base_class_name, wSchema) \
    CObject* PASCAL class_name::CreateObject() \
        { return new class_name; } \
    extern AFX_CLASSINIT _init_##class_name; \
    _IMPLEMENT_RUNTIMECLASS(class_name, base_class_name, wSchema, \
        class_name::CreateObject, &_init_##class_name) \
    AFX_CLASSINIT _init_##class_name(RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name)); \
    CArchive& AFXAPI operator>>(CArchive& ar, class_name* &pOb) \
        { pOb = (class_name*) ar.ReadObject(RUNTIME_CLASS(class_name)); \
            return ar; }
```

The persistence part separated to individual module should also register sth in dll, however it could not be accessed from exe, so is there any way to read these RUNTIME_CLASS info? or shall I make the individual module as static library instead of dll?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Runtime class implementation works for DLLs only if you have an extension DLL. 
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20ytt2wa.aspx).

A standard DLL doesn't share its classes with other modules (here the EXE).

When an [extension DLL is initialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1btd5ea3.aspx) it is placed into the resource chain. And this includes also the CRuntimeClass Object list. The final thing is done inside [AfxInitExtensionModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0et7wsb.aspx) and the constructor of CDynLinkLibrary.

Just look into the code the wizard creates with an extension DLL.

Remember that using this features inside a DLL always requires that the MFC is also used as a DLL.

Creating a static library will fix the problem but if you use such code in a lot of modules it will be better to extract the code in a DLL and also use the MFC as a shared resource.

Comment: problem solved after the module is changed to MFC extension dll as you suggested, thanks again.